# Python 2.6.6 Encoding Error

Tags: python, utf-8

Here's what i get.

ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

Here's my line of code which is throwing error.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT path, filename, size, state, modified, created FROM file WHERE path=? and filename=?", (path,filename))
```

I tried other way too by searching here.
and made my code like.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT path, filename, size, state, modified, created FROM file WHERE path=? and filename=?", (path.decode('utf-8'),filename.decode('utf-8')))
```

But now its giving error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

How to solve it?

Comment: What's in the `path` varialbe?

Comment: path of file in drive.

Comment: No, I mean what is there exactly. What does `print path` returns?

Answer (score 0):

When you decode the 8bits string, you must use its actual encoding, not the database encoding.

If you were using latin1, you have (tested on 2.7.3) :

```
>>> txt = "\xe9\xe8"
>>> txt
'\xe9\xe8'
>>> print txt
éè
>>> utxt = txt.decode("latin1")
>>> utxt
u'\xe9\xe8'
>>> print utxt
éè
```

So you should write :

```
cursor.execute("SELECT path, filename, size, state, modified, created FROM file WHERE path=? and filename=?",
     (path.decode('latin1'),filename.decode('latin1')))
```

replacing `latin1` with **your** encoding.

Comment: tried this. giving this error. `ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.`

Comment: tried ascii too in the place of latin1 and utf-8, but still got "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: @shoaibyaseen : what is your language, and can you give me an example of the non ascii characters you have to deal with ?

Comment: its taking the directory structure of drive. OS language is English US

Comment: @shoaibyaseen I do not care about OS except for character set. What do your file names look like, and specifically **what special characters can they contain** ? And what is **your** language ?

Comment: mostly files are in english, some contains chines  characters too.

Comment: @shoaibyaseen : Fine and what charset is used ? I assume it cannot be latin1 nor windows-1252 ?